# When will Travis-CI support ubuntu 14.04 as the build OS?

Tags: travis-ci

To build C++ code there are various dependencies that aren't available in Ubuntu 12.04 but available in Ubuntu 14.04, for example g++-4.8, boost1.54, etc.

When will Travis-CI support 14.04? or does it already support and how to enable build on 14.04?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806296/choose-a-specific-ubuntu-version

Answer (score 8):

Travis' team recently [announced](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-10-14-opening-up-ubuntu-trusty-beta/)  that they are opening **beta** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS support.

To get started with 14.04 beta add the following two keys in your `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
```

There is also a [milestone](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/milestones/Ubuntu%2014.04%20-%20Trusty%20Tahr) category on Github with some remaining issues which need to be resolved before it goes to stable.

For further information you can read [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/).

Answer (score 3):

There is an [open issue on the Travis CI GitHub repository](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2046) about getting Ubuntu 14.04 support, but there hasn't been much news on it for a long time. I suggest contacting the Travis CI team more directly, perhaps via that issue, if you want an update.

Comment: Unfortunately comments were closed on this issue a while back, probably due to the large number of "me too" requests for this support.  It's certainly a feature our team been wanting for over a year, since we have to go to extreme lengths to get the 12.04 environment set up to build with newer stuff, and for some components like Boost, this is rather difficult (if not almost impossible--apt-get bombs out every time I've tried).

Comment: Reading the Travis blog, it looks like their development effort is going into a containerised setup using Amazon EC2, rather than using their own proper virtualisation on their own hardware.  We'll see how this pans out--our initial tests ran into various resource limitations such as disc space being too tight to do a full C++ build.  Hopefully they will fix the problems here, and get it updated to use 14.04 soon.