# Choose a specific Ubuntu version

Tags: travis-ci

If i'm using the default travis file it looks like that the build machine is Ubuntu Precise.

```
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
```

Is there any tweak to use an trusty or utopic machine?

Answer (score 3):

This is now implemented, add to `.travis.yml`:

```
dist: trusty
```

to use ubuntu trusty.

Answer (score 2):

No. Only Precise. Works are ongoing re Trusty.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2046

Answer (score 0):

The different environments of the Ubuntu version in which Travis CI can run your builds are in the next link: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/

To the date 05/04/2020 the following virtual environments you can choose:

1. Ubuntu Bionic 18.04
2. Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 default
3. Ubuntu Trusty 14.04
4. Ubuntu Precise 12.04